# Retrieve specific string from a file within each commit and combine it with commit's message?

Tags: node.js, windows, git

I'm trying create a changes log file of a repository. For that I'm using command:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%s%n%b" > changes.txt
```

This works great, each commit is separated by an empty line:

```
* 3rd commmit
* another line from 3rd commit

* second commit

* first commit
```

However it doesn't show the version of the commit, which is located inside `myScript.js` file in each commit:

```
// @version 1.2.3
```

How could I retrieve a specific string from a file inside a commit and insert into the `changes.txt` so the result would be:

```
v1.2.0
* 3rd commmit
* another line from 3rd commit

v1.1.3
* second commit

v1.1.2
* first commit
```